# Adding a light gray overlay to a Coverr.co video?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to add a gray overlay on a video from Coverr.co, but still behind the text. I tried using rgba() to add the color and opacity but it doesn't seem to work for me. Heres the code:

```css
.video-container .filter {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
        <div class="filter"></div>
          <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
            <source src="Productive-Morning/MP4/Productive-Morning.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
            <source src="Productive-Morning/WEBM/Productive-Morning.webm" type="video/webm" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
          </video>
        <div class="poster hidden">
            <img src="Productive-Morning/snapshots/Productive-Morning.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. I added a div before the div with class "filter" and then gave it the following CSS:

```
.bg-overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above CSS work only for the current screen not for the scrolled. If you want to overlay this to the complete screen with hatched you can use the following.

```
.bg-overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1; /* this index depends on how much z-index your layout extends. Suppose if any of dom element in page already has an z-index to 1 then this can 2 for this page*/
}
```